# Eggplants at a Jewish Cemetery?

Tags: death, cemetery-grave

[image: Outside the gates of the Mikveh Israel Cemetery are bunch of Eggplants tied tighter with red yarn . A bevy of American coins were under each one .]

This was taken outside the gates of the Mikveh Israel Cemetery. There are bunch of Eggplants tied tighter with red yarn . A bevy of American coins were under each one.

Typically eggplants at a cemetery are an offering to the spirit Oya.

Is there a Jewish meaning/ritual for this, as well? Or is this an attempt at syncretism?